# click play button iframe react

Tags: reactjs, video, iframe

I have an iframe video with a play button (not youtube!). There is no autoplay functionality. So, I want onLoad imitate click this button. How can I achieve this? I know the class of the button, I want to use it.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to access the elements inside the iframe being loaded from a third-party resource.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, example: declare a boolean state and append `autoplay=1` to the url on click. Only works for web browsers.

`const [play, setPlay] = useState(false);`

`const url = play ? "urEmbededUrl?autoplay=1" : urEmbededUrl`

```
<iframe
 src={url}
 title={""}
 height="100%"
 width="100%"
 allow="autoplay;"
 />
```

`<button onClick={() => setPlay(true)}>play</button>`

Note that `allow="autoplay;"` is required.